# I think my XML parser is clunky

Tags: android

I have the following bit of code that reads data from an XML file.  I've been working on it for quite a while now, and after finally getting it to work, I am wondering if this is the best way to do this.

Just looking at the code and it looks clunky and cumbersome.  But it does work.

Am I doing this all wrong?

Thanks

```
public void getEncounterStats(Activity activity, int id)
throws XmlPullParserException, IOException
{
Resources res = activity.getResources();
XmlResourceParser xpp = res.getXml(R.xml.encounters);
xpp.next();
String elName = "";
//encounterID is the ID of the encounter
int encounterID = id;
//attribID is the attribute ID in the XML file
int attribID = 0;
int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
{

 if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT)
 {      

 }
 else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
 {
     if(encounterID >= 0) {
         if(xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("creature")) {
             System.out.println("inside while loop --- "+xpp.getName());
             try {
                 attribID = Integer.parseInt(xpp.getAttributeValue(0));
             } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                 Log.e("attribute value error", e.getMessage());
             }
             //DETERMINE ELEMENT NAME and set elName
         } else if(xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {
             System.out.println("inside while loop --- "+xpp.getName());
             elName = "name";
         } else if(xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("race")) {
             elName = xpp.getName();
         } else if(xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("gender")) {
             elName = xpp.getName();
         } else if(xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("alignment")) {
             elName = xpp.getName();
         } else if(xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("age")) {
             elName = xpp.getName();
         } else if(xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("condition")){
             elName = xpp.getName();
         } else if(xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item1")) {
             elName = xpp.getName();
         } else if(xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item2")) {
             elName = xpp.getName();
         }
     }
 } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
     //end tag
 }  else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
     //COLLECT DATA
     //check to make sure the attribID == the encounterID...will only pull data from correct ID
     if (attribID == encounterID) {
         if(elName.equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {
            setName(xpp.getText());
            System.out.println("name is  " + this.name);
         } else if(elName.equalsIgnoreCase("race"))  {
            setRace(xpp.getText());
         } else if(elName.equalsIgnoreCase("gender")) {
            setGender(xpp.getText()); 
         } else if(elName.equalsIgnoreCase("age")) {
             try {
                 setAge(Integer.parseInt(xpp.getText()));
             } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                 Log.e("encounter.age error", e.getMessage());
             }
         } else if(elName.equalsIgnoreCase("alignment")) {
             setAlignment(xpp.getText());
         } else if(elName.equalsIgnoreCase("condition")) {
             setCondition(xpp.getText());
         } else if(elName.equalsIgnoreCase("item1")) {
             setItem1(xpp.getText());
         } else if(elName.equalsIgnoreCase("item2")) {
             setItem2(xpp.getText());
         } else {
             System.out.println("Nothing here "+xpp.getName());
         }
     }
 }
 eventType = xpp.next();

}     


}
```

Comment: Switch statements are always a good alternative to if...elseif blocks.

Comment: Other than making the if...else blocks into a switch, it looks good to me.

Comment: I guess I was concerned that the way I am looking up the data is convoluted.  Because I first run through the XML file and get the elementName...then I store that in a variable called elName.  Then I run through elName...I guess it just leaves a bad taste in my mouth and I'm wondering if I am doing this completely wrong.

Comment: Just keep in mind that XML parsing on Android should be kept to a minimum to avoid performance problems. An alternative would be a way to compile your XML files into a compact binary format, and a binary runtime parser that can reconstruct the data in a linear fashion. This would offer higher performance than parsing XML files at runtime.

Comment: If not XML, whats the best way to store data for an Android app?  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly recommend you to look into [SimpleXML](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) which is an XML API for java in general. Works great in Android. I have tried it myself so with the examples in their website it shouldn't be a problem for you to integrate it with what you have quick enough. It makes the whole thing automatically.. you would just need to setup every object represented in the xml as a class and set up its attributes.

In the end you would handle each entity as a class and use their methods to access whatever var in them.

Good luck.